# Spark save to elasticsearch failed due to Connection error

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to index data in elasticsearch about 77M documents with 150 fields . 
We dont have much computing/memory resource so our cluster is 3 nodes ( 48GB RAM /24 CPU and 6TB of storage )

I'm sending data from another spark cluster in another virtual network but the two networks are paired and I CAN PING ALL the els nodes from the spark cluster nodes .

the problem that I'm facing :  is that at a certain amount of documents indexed ( about 8M )  spark cannot connect to els  and it throws the following error :

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 173 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 173.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 17160, wn21-swspar.of12wietsveu3a3voc5bflf1pa.ax.internal.cloudapp.net, executor 3): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[10.0.0.12:9200]] 
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:149)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:466)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:450)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:186)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:248)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:270)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.doWriteToIndex(RestRepository.java:210)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.writeToIndex(RestRepository.java:187)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:67)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:101)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know what can cause this.  Is the cluster size ( RAM/CPU)  not enougth or is there a special configuration for indexes with huge amount of data ? 
what I'm sure about is  that it's not a network problem . 
ELS version : 6.2.4

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Spark tries to make so many requests that your ES cluster can't handle.
Check this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html to tune more how you're sending the data to ES, check those :

- es.batch.size.bytes
- es.batch.size.entries
- es.batch.write.retry.count
- es.http.retries
- es.http.timeout

And please check too how you want to route the requests, using es.nodes.client.only, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

i had a problem like that and i fixed it by changing the size of the index. 
In other words ,the default size of an index is 1000 .

Change the index size by changing the settings : "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000 ( for example )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing this issue because of unassigned primary shards for the index, due to which its failing to connect to ES. Could you check the logs if there is any shard unassigned issue.?

For flexibility I use elasticsearch-head chrome plugin to monitor the ES for any such errors.

Comment: I've set up a grafana dashboard to monitor the cluster and I don't see any unassigned primary shards so I think it's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was using AWS Elasticsearch and Spark in EMR. After tweaking aforementioned configurations, I found out that the problem was still unsolved. After some research/debugging, I decreased **spark.default.parallelism** to smaller value and the issue was resolved.

In my opinion, this is because excessive requests from Spark when **spark.default.parallelism** is set to a large number will put too much burden on Elasticsearch. Check memory usage during ingestion time. It is likely that they went up pretty high making ES cluster hectic.

Be mindful that I still get **Connection error** after decreasing **spark.default.parallelism**. However, from Spark Job-point of view, it was no longer an error since they were all resolved during retry period. With some high **spark.default.parallelism**, the entire Job failed even after retries.

The exact value of **spark.default.parallelism** might vary depending on your input data size and Spark cluster size. You could try decreasing the value gradually until you find the right number.